# lambda expressions in string interpolation

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to use lambda expressions in string interpolation, this way:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var a = $@"test { () => {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var v in new string[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" })
        sb.Append(v);
    return sb.ToString();
}} test";
var b = $@"test {F1()} test";

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);

string F1()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var v in new string[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" })
        sb.Append(v);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
test System.Func`1[System.String] test
test abcdefghi test
```

The actual use case is more complex: I have a string that contains a mail body in html format, and I need to insert several table rows in a couple of places.
I thought it would be a good idea to place forach loops in lambda expression: I find the result very readable this way.

Unfortunatly, I see that c# invokes ToString() on the expression, rather than returing the expression value itself.

This does not happen if I call an external function.

Comment: Even though you've added it to the string, the lambda expression hasn't been invoked.

Comment: "This does not happen if I call an external function." -> because you're **calling** it, rather than just defining it as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that c# invokes ToString() on the expression

Yes, because it's seeing the delegate as an object, and lacking anything more specific in its understanding of what to do with an object, it's just calling ToString() on it.

There's a critical difference between your two attempts, which might become more clear if I pull the delegate out:

```
var f = () => {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var v in new string[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" })
        sb.Append(v);
    return sb.ToString();
};
        
var a = $@"test {f} test";
var b = $@"test {F1()} test";

var c = $@"test {f()} test";
```

`F1` is invoked because it's proceeded by `()` and its returned result is included in the string. `f` is not invoked, so *what f is itself* becomes the thing that is included into the string

`var c` version works as you might expect.. (And in my opinion would be a cleaner way to structure it; a local function would also clean it up)

You might also want to consider in this particular case:

```
var d = $@"test {new[]{"abc","def","ghi"}.Concat()} test"
```

Comment: Does the delegate need to be moved out?

Comment: Thank you, I understand my mistake. My goal is to keep foreach instructions inside the string body as I find it to be more readable. I tried to modify {f()} in several ways: {(()=>{...})()} - {()=>{...}()} but none of them worked. I also found out that I can do var f = () => {...}; var r = f.Invoke(); but I can't do var r = (()=>{...}).Invoke();

Comment: Er.. I suppose you could cast it to a Func that returns the requested type and invoke it e.g. `$"hello {((Func<string>)(() => "hello"))()} world"`, or make some helper like `private T Exec<T>(Func<T> x) => x();` and then `$"hello {Exec(() => "hello")} world"` it... It's really messy code though to slap all that in the middle of a interpstring. I'd take it out if I came across it